# Qual a diferença entre as tags <b></b> e <strong></strong>?

Tags: html, html-tags

Olá, Comunidade!

Eu tenho uma dúvida sobre o uso das tags `<b></b>` e `<strong></strong>`. Já procurei em alguns sites, mas não encontrei uma comparação que diferenciasse as duas tags, somente o uso delas.

Qual a diferença entre essas tags? Por que têm o mesmo estilo? Quando devo usar cada uma (qual o contexto)? Existe problema de usá-las fora de seus contextos apropriados?

A mesma dúvida se estende às tags `<i></i>` e `<em></em>`.

Tá aqui um [JSFiddle/snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/ndLbend4/10/) para exemplificar o que estou dizendo.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Calibri Light', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h3>
    Usando <i>bold</i> 
</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <b>consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Sed ut dictum ex, ut efficitur nibh. Donec accumsan.
</p>
<h3>
    Usando <i>strong</i> 
</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Sed ut dictum ex, ut efficitur nibh. Donec accumsan.
</p>
<h3>
    Usando <i>italic</i> 
</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <i>consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Sed ut dictum ex, ut efficitur nibh. Donec accumsan.
</p>
<h3>
    Usando <i>emphasis</i> 
</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing elit</em>. Sed ut dictum ex, ut efficitur nibh. Donec accumsan.
</p>
```

**O HTML no geral não parece apresentar problemas sérios para o desenvolvedor (*bugs*) quanto ao mal uso. O que pode se considerar a partir disso? Qual tipo de problema que eu posso enfrentar pelo mal uso de tags HTML?**

Comment: @Bacco, eu editei o post e coloquei minha última pergunta em negrito. Será que você pode me ajudar com ela também? Eu vi a resposta do link e ela é perfeita para a primeira parte. Obrigado!

Comment: A pergunta original tem um "Quando e **por que** usar cada um deles?", talvez as respostas de lá estejam deixando um pouco a desejar, mas ainda me parece ser o mesmo problema. Tenho a impressão que não tem diferença suficiente pra duas perguntas separadas no site, mas se você fizer uma mais específica sobre o uso semanticamente incorreto das tags, aí talvez o enfoque mude (e seria mais abrangente que os elementos mencionados). Agora, o maior cuidado seria elaborar de maneira a demandar respostas mais técnicas do que opinativas.

Comment: Oh! Você está correto! Acatarei sua opinião!!! Obrigado!

Comment: Pense nessa possibilidade de elaborar uma mais focada sobre a importância da semântica correta em HTML, acho que não tem nenhuma no site (ao menos, numa pesquisa rápida, não achei). Em todo o caso, compensa uma boa pesquisada, e ao elaborar, ter cuidado de não cair nos problemas de fechamento do site (ampla demais, baseada em opinião, etc)

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade visualmente nenhuma, a diferença esta para deficientes fisicos ou deveria ser, quando um browser para cegos identifica a palavra strong, entre as tags a leitura é feita com maior ênfase. Porem visualmente elas tem o mesmo objetivo negritar uma palavra